# "sudo -u postgres psql postgres" does not ask for password

Tags: postgresql, logins, password, debian

I've taken over a system using postgres. When logging in, if I use ...

```
sudo -u postgres psql postgres
```

...it does NOT ask for a password. However, if I do ...

```
psql -U postgres -h localhost postgres
```

... it asks for the password.

Why? 
How is this difference configured?
Can it be configured for a different user to login this way?

(NOTE: user `postgres` is NOT in the `sudoers` file, or in the sudo group.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Postgres has a type of authentication called **peer**. If you look at pg_hba.conf you may see something like

```
local   all             postgres                       peer
```

or like

```
local   all             all                            peer
```

The fact you did not get asked for the password has nothing to do with using sudo and everything to do with the fact that you were connecting to a DB that matched the user name and peer authentication was enabled in pg_hba.conf.

If this is a test machine and security is not needed you can use trust instead of peer and then passwords will not be needed. Can not stress enough, trust is only a good option for development and test machines. One should never, ever, use trust on a production  machine.