# psql does not require a password on macOS with Postgres.app

Tags: psql

When opening the `psql` console, there is no password prompt. This behaviour is the same for all postgres users. I can basically do everything without a password. This seems rather unsafe.

How do I enable password checking? I'm running macOS Mojave and use Postgres.app with postgresql version 10.

This is the command I use:

```
psql -Umyuser # this user has a password set
```

Comment: In lieu of posting a self-answered question, it would be tidier (and polite) to upvote the Q&A where you found the solution or to post a new answer there if you feel you have something productive to add 

Comment: I was in doubt about this one. It is subtly different, since sudo is involved, so it could be argued to be a different question. But in any case it was not my intention to be impolite, will definitely keep your remarks in mind!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer in [another post](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/198125/sudo-u-postgres-psql-postgres-does-not-ask-for-password) on stackexchange.

I've edited the authentication lines in `pg_hba.conf` and changed "trust" into "password" for all lines. It now looks like this:

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

local   all             all                                     password
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            password
host    all             all             ::1/128                 password
local   replication     all                                     password
host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            password
host    replication     all             ::1/128                 password
```

Now `psql` asks me for a password every time.

Comment: From PostgreSQL docs: 

"password - 

Require the client to supply an unencrypted password for authentication. Since the password is sent in clear text over the network, this should not be used on untrusted networks."